# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

Tags: python, numpy

This is part of the code I am working on. Look at the last line.

```
def xyz2srgb(xyz):
    """Convert from XYZ colorspace to sRGB"""
    xyz = xyz.T
    srgb = N.zeros_like(xyz)
    srgb[0] = 3.241*xyz[0] - 1.5374*xyz[1] - 0.4986*xyz[2]
    srgb[1] = -0.9692*xyz[0] + 1.876*xyz[1] + 0.0416*xyz[2]
    srgb[2] = 0.0556*xyz[0] - 0.204*xyz[1] + 1.057*xyz[2]

    srgb /= float(srgb.max())

    a = 0.055
    srgb = N.where(srgb <= 0.0031308,
                12.92*srgb,
                (1+a)*srgb**(1/2.4)-a)
```

It throws an error:

```
 ./example.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  (1+a)*srgb**(1/2.4)-a)
```

Is this some range limit? I found a similar thread on SO: [Numpy error: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140744/numpy-error-invalid-value-encountered-in-power)

Any clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should print out the values of `srgb`.  Probably it's not a range error, it's that the negative coefficients here

```
srgb[0] = 3.241*xyz[0] - 1.5374*xyz[1] - 0.4986*xyz[2]
srgb[1] = -0.9692*xyz[0] + 1.876*xyz[1] + 0.0416*xyz[2]
srgb[2] = 0.0556*xyz[0] - 0.204*xyz[1] + 1.057*xyz[2]
```

make it entirely possible that elements of `srgb` can be negative, and unless you're already working in complex numbers, you'll raise a warning when you take the power:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.array([-2.0])
array([-2.])
>>> numpy.array([-2.0])**(1/2.4)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
array([ nan])
>>> numpy.array([-2.0+0j])**(1/2.4)
array([ 0.34548198+1.28935629j])
```

The arguments to `where` will be evaluated before they're passed, so the powers will be taken before the branch on the `srgb <= 0.0031308` condition divides up the values, and the warning is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

For these error you can use  the float in the exponent. for example :

```
>>> test = np.linspace(0,10,1000);)

>>> expos = 2*np.power(test,**6.**)+2*np.power(test,**4.**)
```

Best regards