# Python Maxent Classifier

Tags: python, nltk, maxent

I've been using the maxent classifier in python and its failing and I don't understand why.

I'm using the movie reviews corpus.
(total noob)

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
 return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
classifier = MaxentClassifier.train(trainfeats)
```

This is the error (I know I'm doing this wrong please link to how Maxent works)

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\maxent.py", line 1334
>       sum1 = numpy.sum(exp_nf_delta * A, axis=0)
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\maxent.py", line 1335
>       sum2 = numpy.sum(nf_exp_nf_delta * A, axis=0)
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\maxent.py", line 1341
>       deltas -= (ffreq_empirical - sum1) / -sum2
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140744/numpy-error-invalid-value-encountered-in-power) be the same problem, maybe?

Comment: BTW, NLTK uses maxent classifier of scipy. Maxent classifier has been removed in the scipy starting 0.11(http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/reference/maxentropy.html).  Maxent classification may not work in NLTK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a fix for the `numpy` overflow issue but since this is just a movie review classifier for learning NLTK / text classification (and you probably don't want training to take a long time anyway), I'll provide a simple workaround: you can just restrict the words used in feature sets.

You can find the `300` most commonly used words in all reviews like this (you can obviously make that higher if you want),

```
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(word for word in movie_reviews.words())
top_words = set(all_words.keys()[:300])
```

Then all you have to do is cross-reference `top_words` in your feature extractor for reviews. Also, just as a suggestion, it's more efficient to use dictionary comprehension rather than convert a `list` of `tuple`s to a `dict`. So this might look like,

```
def word_feats(words):
    return {word:True for word in words if word in top_words}
```

Answer (score 6):

I changed and update the code a bit.

```
import nltk, nltk.classify.util, nltk.metrics
from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.probability import FreqDist, ConditionalFreqDist
from sklearn import cross_validation


from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
 return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
#classifier = nltk.MaxentClassifier.train(trainfeats)

algorithm = nltk.classify.MaxentClassifier.ALGORITHMS[0]
classifier = nltk.MaxentClassifier.train(trainfeats, algorithm,max_iter=3)

classifier.show_most_informative_features(10)

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(word for word in movie_reviews.words())
top_words = set(all_words.keys()[:300])

def word_feats(words):
    return {word:True for word in words if word in top_words}
```