# ValueError with solve_ivp because of RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations

I'm developing an evolutionary model, of which a shortened (and therefore biologically senseless) version looks like this:

```
n = 300 # population size
no_gens = 600 # total number of generations
R = 1000 # relative timescale of environmental variation
P = 0.9 # environmental predictability

def environment(t):
    E = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * t / R) + 1) / 2
    mu_env = 0.5 * (1 - P) + P * E
    sigma_env = 0.5 * (1 - P) / 3
    C = np.random.normal(mu_env, sigma_env)
    return E, C

# initial population
def create_pop(n):    
    pop = np.zeros(n, dtype=[('E','<f8'), ('C','<f8'), ('hill','<f8'), ('phenotype','<f8'), ('fitness','<f8'), 
                             ('G','<f8'), ('basal','<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('alpha','<f8')])
    pop['G'] = np.random.random(n)
    pop['b'] = np.random.random(n)
    pop['hill'] = 1
    return pop

def phenotype(pop):
    pop['basal'] = pop['G'] + pop['b'] * pop['C']
    def phenotype_ode(t_ode, x):
        dxdt = pop['basal'] - x + pop['alpha'] * (1 / (1 + x ** (-pop['hill'])))
        return dxdt
    t_end = 1e02
    sol_lower = solve_ivp(phenotype_ode, [0, t_end], np.zeros(n), method='BDF')
    lower_steady_states = sol_lower.y[:, -1]
    return lower_steady_states

def mutation(pop):
    if np.random.random() <= 0.001:
        pop['G'] += np.random.normal(0, 0.05, n)
        pop['G'][np.flatnonzero(pop['G'] < 0)] = 0
        pop['G'][np.flatnonzero(pop['G'] > 1)] = 1
    if np.random.random() <= 0.001:
        pop['b'] += np.random.normal(0, 0.05, n)
        pop['b'][np.flatnonzero(pop['b'] < 0)] = 0
        pop['b'][np.flatnonzero(pop['b'] > 1)] = 1
    if np.random.random() <= 0.001:
        pop['hill'] += np.random.normal(0, 0.05, n)
        pop['hill'][np.flatnonzero(pop['hill'] < 1)] = 1
    if np.random.random() <= 0.001:
        pop['alpha'] += np.random.normal(0, 0.05, n)
        pop['alpha'][np.flatnonzero(pop['alpha'] < 0)] = 0

def reproduction(pop):
    mutation(pop)
    pop['phenotype'] = phenotype(pop)
    return pop

# iteration
pop = create_pop(n)
for t in progressbar.progressbar(range(no_gens+1)):
    enviro = environment(t)
    pop['E'] = enviro[0]
    pop['C'] = enviro[1]
    pop = reproduction(pop)
```

With a sufficiently large number of generations, there may occur a

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`, finally leading to

`ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs` (if I'm reading the error message correctly).

Having read [Numpy error: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140744/numpy-error-invalid-value-encountered-in-power), I was assuming a data type issue. The `dtype` of `pop['hill']` is `'<f8'`. If I'm not mistaken, `np.dtype('f8')` is equivalent to `np.int64` (see, for example, https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.09-structured-data-numpy.html), i.e., exactly the data type for which all went well in the above SO link. Does the issue then have to do with the "little endian" (`<`)?

Or am I completely barking up the wrong tree here??

P.S. Of course, I can post the complete error message (>30 lines), if this helps!

Comment: You could try writing the last term as `1/(1+x**(-pop['hill']))`, underflow being rounded to `0` allows to continue operations more often than overflow giving NaN values. If it is indeed this exponentiation that results in the error.

Comment: Try changing the integration method, perhaps you're working with a stiff differential equation. Hope it helps

Comment: @LutzL: Thanks for the advice to re-write the last term, this is really helpful because it makes further programming easier. However, judging from a few test runs, it does not seem to help with the actual issue here. Do you think this means that the error does not come from the exponentiation?

Comment: @TavoGLC: Thanks for this, but I'm already using `method='BDF'` which should work for stiff problems...

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example where the error occurs? Including the definition of `pop` for this example.

Comment: @LutzL: Ok. I tried to find a MWE, but it still has 65 lines and is too long for a comment. And unfortunately, it does not even seem to reproduce the error, at least judging from a few test runs that all finished without error (might of course be just a lucky accident). Any idea how I could show you this MWE? Your help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54542450/edit) the question to add additional information. If the problem is not easy to replicate, how sure are you that it is really a problem with the ODE integrator? If there are `NaN` or `inf` in the exponent, the error might lie in the preparation of the exponents, that you somehow divide by zero or produce overflow without triggering an error interrupt at this earlier point.

Comment: @LutzL: I've edited the question and added code. I know the long code block looks terrible, but I just can't find out what produces the error. I'm pretty sure, though, that both the `environment` function and the `mutation` function are necessary to replicate the error (or at least parts of them). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @LutzL: In case you haven't seen, I've found a better MWE and made it into a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811977/strange-case-of-valueerror-array-must-not-contain-infs-or-nans

Comment: I've seen it. What exactly is "<f8" and why do you use it? I do not know this type, is this something fixed-point? Hopefully someone with knowlegde looks over this question and can clarify. // With a minimal example I thought about that let the program keep a log of the parameters used so that in the case of the error you can easily find the parameter records of that error, so that you can have a reproducible error with a minimal parameter set. Then you do not need to post the whole evolution algorithm.